# How to save pointers to every object of class

Tags: c++, oop, stl

I need the method for my class, which will return pointers to every object of this class. So I decided to use:

```
static set<Class> objects;
```

My class:
using namespace std;

```
class Class{
    private:
        static set<Class> objects;
        string name;
    public:
        Class(string name);
        string getName() const;
        static set<Class> getObjects();
        void show() const;
        ~Class();
};
```

But I get errors in constructor:

```
Class::Class(string name){
    this->name = name;
    objects.insert(*this);
}
```

So, the question is: how to create the method to get all objects of my class?
Maybe its wrong way?

Comment: Exactly what error do you get?

Comment: Wouldn't you want `set<Class*>` to store pointers?

Comment: Don't forget about copy constructor and destructor. And store pointers to objects not their copies.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/6f2rdjvl7/ - link to error description screenshot

Comment: Actually you probably want to use `unordered_set<Class*>`.

Comment: If I try to store pointers in static set I get error template argument is invalid

Comment: This could work I guess: ideone.com/cvlIGW or even: http://ideone.com/CLuKPU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified my previous answer to adjust the solution according to the additional details you provided. To count the instances of individual class instances you can use the following solution that makes use of a CRTP'ish pattern:

```
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;


template <typename T>
class InstanceCouner
{
public:
    static const set<T*>& GetInstances()
    {
        return GetWritableInstances();
    }
protected:
    InstanceCouner()
    {
        GetWritableInstances().insert(static_cast<T*>(this));
    }
    ~InstanceCouner()
    {
        GetWritableInstances().erase(static_cast<T*>(this));
    }
private:
    static set<T*>& GetWritableInstances()
    {
        static set<T*> instances;
        return instances;
    }
};

class Class : InstanceCouner<Class>
{
public:
    Class(const string& _name) : name(_name) {}
    const string& GetName() const { return name; }
private:
    string name;
};

class Derived : InstanceCouner<Derived>, public Class
{
public:
    Derived(const string& _name) : Class(_name) {}
};

int test()
{
    unique_ptr<Class> cls(new Class("base"));
    unique_ptr<Derived> derived(new Derived("derived"));

    const set<Class*>& base_instances = InstanceCouner<Class>::GetInstances();
    const set<Derived*>& derived_instances = InstanceCouner<Derived>::GetInstances();

    cout << "base instances: " << base_instances.size() << endl;
    cout << "derived instances: " << derived_instances.size() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's can be solution for one class. But I need to inheritate this mechanism by few successors.

Comment: @Azazell00 Modified my answer, this latter solution does what you want and it works with Meyer's singleton, this latter decision can be changed into a static variable that is unsafe/buggy (although more performant) when it comes to creating instances in during static initialization.